# Query showing when a rental is overdue?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting error code: 1064 and can't seem to figure how to qrite this query correctly.

```
SELECT CONCAT(customer.last_name, ' , ', customer.first_name) AS customer,
customer.phone_number, video.title
FROM rental INNER JOIN customer ON rental.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer
INNER JOIN video ON rental.idVideo = video.idVideo
WHERE rental.return_date IS NULL
AND rent_date + INTERVAL DAY < CURRENT_DATE()
LIMIT 7;
```

I'm trying to create an event that will show who has a video currently rented that is overdue. It looks right to me thought I must be missing something!

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Comment: oh my! let me try it with an    ORDER BY    rent_date.

Comment: Error 1064 usually points to the place in the code with the error.

Comment: I added the    ORDER BY rent_date; still getting error 1064 it seems to be pinpointing line 7 which is "limit 7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is:

```
WHERE rental.return_date IS NULL AND
      rent_date + INTERVAL DAY < CURRENT_DATE()
--------------------------^ ???
```

You need some number of days.  I don't know what the correct value is.

Comment: you sir are brilliant! I was stuck on this for a good hour! thank you it worked! I got rid of limit 7 thinking that would add 7 days from the date it was rented the code now looks like this;      SELECT CONCAT(customer.last_name, ' , ', customer.first_name) AS customer,
 customer.phone_number, video.title
    FROM rental INNER JOIN customer ON rental.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer
    INNER JOIN video ON rental.idVideo = video.idVideo
    WHERE rental.return_date IS NULL
    AND rent_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY < CURRENT_DATE()
    ORDER BY rent_date;         thank you

Comment: Why didn't I spot it? Sigh.